# An outlier occurs when I use a loop to assign a value to a unidirectional list

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I create a structure, and when I assign a value to it using a linked list, I set a pointer. When the first loop ends, the value is exactly what I want. However, when the second loop starts, something is wrong with the data
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

Here is some of the key code

```
   char* filename = cls->mailgateway_custom_rulepath;
    fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st* fangmail_rule = (fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st*)malloc(sizeof(fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st));
    fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st* p = fangmail_rule;

      
    FILE* fp;                                                   //create file pointer
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");                                  // open file only read
    char* a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(filename));                  //creat char point save str from file
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", a) != EOF)
    {
        /*fscanf(fp, "%s", a);*/
        json_get_from_file = json_tokener_parse(a);
        /* fscanf(fp, "%s", a);
         LOGGER_DEBUG("fcans is %s", a);
         json_get_from_file = json_tokener_parse(a);
         LOGGER_DEBUG("tokener %s is ", json_object_to_json_string(json_get_from_file));*/
        
        LOGGER_DEBUG("fangmial type is %d", fangmail_rule->type);//again error
/****************************json parse***************************/
        LOGGER_DEBUG("fangmail type is %d" ,fangmail_rule->type);
        LOGGER_DEBUG("p type is %d" ,p->type);
        p->next = (fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st*)malloc(sizeof(fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st));
        p = p->next;   
        LOGGER_DEBUG("fangmail type2 is %d", fangmail_rule->type);//right
        LOGGER_DEBUG("p type2 is %d", p->type);
    }
```

structures is

```
typedef struct _fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st
{
    /******some variable***********/
    struct _fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st* next;
}fangmail_eml_custom_rule_st;
```

Comment: `char* a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(filename));` This will allocate only 4 or 8 bytes (the size of one pointer) Is this enough size to read words from the file?

Comment: Thank you very much. As a mystery, it turned out that the memory space I applied for could not meet the requirement of string storage, which caused the problem of read and write coverage. You saved my time for a whole afternoon